How many ways to color a circular pattern of regions such that no adjacent regions share the same color
Suppose that we have four regions $A,B,C,D$ arranged in a circular form e.g. $A$ precedes $B$, $B$ precedes $C$, $C$ precedes $D$, and $D$ precedes $A$.
Using $4$ colors, how many ways can we color each region such that no adjacent regions share the same color?
This is easier when there are $3$ regions: $4$ colors for $A$, $3$ colors for $B$ and since $C$ is between $A$ and $B$ (and $A$ and $B$ are of different colors), there are only $2$ color choices for $C$. So the total is $4*3*2$.
The problem with $4$ (or more regions) is that $A$ and $C$ can be of the same colors or of different colors. So the same counting method doesn't apply. I'm not sure how to reformulate the problem here. Any hints that will help generalize this?

Do all 4 colors have to be used with each coloring?  Alternatively, are you for example) allowed to use 2 of one color, and 1 each of two of the other three colors?

Please see this article on MathSE protocol.

Not necessary to use all 4 colors.

Hint: My approach would be to start with the partition of an integer $~n$, such as $~n = 4.$

With $n=4$ a case analysis isn't too onerous. You can treat the cases when $A$ and $C$ have the same colour and when they have different colours separately. This might even give you a hint for how you could approach the problem for general $n$.
